# Why do I get a invalid syntax error on this statement?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, error

The script was working fine, until I added the screech.volume property. I didn't edit the 'if' statement in any way, but somehow I get this error on the line of the 'if' statement:

```
File "D:\Users\Jens Hendriks\Documents\Blend-files\Bobsleigh car.blend\pitch n volume", line 17
    if radar.positive:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

the code:

```
    import bge
import math

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
sound = cont.actuators['Sound']
radar = cont.sensors['Radar']
wind = cont.actuators['wind']
screech = cont.actuators['screech']

speed = own.localLinearVelocity.y
xspeed = math.pwr((own.localLinearVelocity.x), 2)
sound.pitch = (math.sqrt(speed)) * .06 + .3
sound.volume = (math.sqrt(speed)) / 20
screech.volume = math.sqrt(math.pow((xspeed),2) / 400

if radar:
    cont.activate(sound)
    wind.volume = (math.sqrt(speed)) / 20
else:
    cont.deactivate(sound)
    wind.volume = .2 + (math.sqrt(speed)) / 20

cont.activate(wind)
cont.activate(screech)
```

What happened to my "beautiful" code!? :(

Comment: 3 opening braces in `screech.volume = math.sqrt(math.pow((xspeed),2) / 400` only two closing.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! That did the trick. I don't know why blender said the error was in line 17 while it was actually in line 15.

Comment: braces allow multi line code in python, making this kind of error msg common.

Comment: @batFINGER: it would be nice to publish that as answer that Hendriks3D can mark it as resolved - thanks